# Browser Local storage and SSL

Tags: ssl, local-storage

This is in reference to my work site: []

This link will be removed when my question is answered :(

We are using the browsers local storage to store the users cart. So when adding an item to the cart notice the mini cart will keep in sync as you would expect.

Here are the steps to reproduce the bug.

1. Add item to cart under non SSL page
2. Navigate to cart. (which is under SSL)
3. Increase quantity by 1 on the cart page
4. Navigate back to an insecure page
5. Notice the minicart is not correct

This is happening because there are essentially two versions of local storage, 1 under SSL and 1 under an insecure page. How do I invalidate the insecure localstorage from the secure page?

Requirement: We need the cart page to be under SSL

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the HTML5 spec, localStorage can not be transferred from HTTP to HTTPS.

The easiest way would be to store all localStorage off of one domain. Ex: `https://www.example.com`

See: [Is there any workaround to make use of html5 localstorage on both http and https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502469/is-there-any-workaround-to-make-use-of-html5-localstorage-on-both-http-and-https) for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

## working example in production

The way I did this was to use an iframe that does a postMessage to its parent. The iframe is always on https but the parent can be either http or https. This solution assumes the modifications are on SSL only to the storage and syncs it back for non SSL but you could adapt this to send modifications both ways so the non ssl parent sends changes down to the ssl child.

**ssl iframe source (storage-sync.html):**

```
if (sessionStorage.cart)
  try {
    var obj = { cart: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.cart) };
    parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(obj), 'http://yourdomain.com');
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
  }
```

**ssl/non ssl parent source:**

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(ev) {
  if (ev.origin !== 'https://yourdomain.com')
    return;
  try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(ev.data);
    sessionStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(obj.cart);
    cart.reload();
  } catch(ex) {};
});

$('body').append('<iframe style="display:none" src="https://yourdomain.com/storage-sync.html?r=' + Math.random() + '"></iframe>');
```

Placing the target origins to the right protocols ensures you won't be sending messages to wrong ones.