# ONLY Safari iframe content load error

Tags: meteor, iframe, safari, easyxdm

I'm running the latest Meteor version v1.3.3.1. This is my scenario. I have an Meteor App. think of Disqus, So I embed a link 'http://frontend.dev:4000' to a webpage in 'http://localhost:8000'

The emebed works and function as expected on every other browser. But On safari I get this error. I'm sure it's a Meteor Issue because when I try to embed any other website from the internet it works alright on Safari. The website shows up ( if not blocked from the website provider ) without any error messages

I'm happy to provide any information you may need

[image]
Also tracking this here. I think this could be a Meteor issue too
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7246

Comment: Looks like `frontend.dev` is trying to access the top frame. Try to determine which code causes it.

Comment: I'm only sending messages over EasyXDM. If you have Safari please check this JSfiddle with your developer > console open you will see the error https://jsfiddle.net/e9exn2pd/

Comment: Here is another MeteorJS app in a iframe with the same error https://jsfiddle.net/e9exn2pd/3/ ( Safari ONLY )

Comment: Its weird because if the code is not working on all browsers sure, but this is only Safari, so a but baffled as to what to do and not so helpful error

Comment: This might just be an error in the console, not an actual failing error. Based on the line numbers, it appears to be related to this bit of ES5 shim code, though I'm not sure exactly why: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/406f0ffcbd9e2df4a6e074fcee351cd434808a8a/es5-shim.js#L997-L1012

Comment: No this is an error. when the error comes on. If you know MeteorJS the login / Signup does does not log the user in too.. There are no login tokens or anything when I check the devtools > localstorage So this is NOT JUST an error.. Need to fix this somehow

Comment: Well *that* issue sounds like it would be caused by Safari's aggressive blocking of 3rd party cookies and other data storage. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20401751

Comment: But the thing is that crator.io login signup works and the localstorage is used to save the Meteor login tokens inside an iframe ? it is Meteor V1.2 is this how the server setup ??