# Safari setting localStorage inside iframe is not correctly shared

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, iframe, local-storage

**EDITED description:**

I have `example.com` which hosts an iframe to `app.example.com/signup`. Whenever `app.example.com/signup` loads, I want to set a localStorage item for `app.example.com` from within the iframe:

```
---------------------------------------
| example.com                         |
|                                     |
|         ___________________________ |
|         | app.example.com/signup  | |
|         |        (iframe)         | |
|         |                         | |
|         | 'coupon': 'discount30'  | |
|         |_________________________| |
|_____________________________________|
```

`example.com` code:

```
<iframe src="https://app.example.com/signup"></iframe>
```

`app.example.com/signup` code:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem('coupon', 'discount30');
</script>

// Signup form
```

Then when I go to `app.example.com` (not `/signup`), I want to be able to access the storageItem I created previously from within the iframe

```
---------------------------------------
| app.example.com                     |
|                                     |
| 'coupon' localStorage does not exist|
|_____________________________________|
```

but it looks like it's not persisted (or I can't access it); Although the iframe `app.example.com/signup` and `app.example.com` share the same domain.

The most closely related issue I encountered was this one: [Iframe localStorage on Safari and Safari mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401751/iframe-localstorage-on-safari-and-safari-mobile)

Comment: I edited the description, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Big time! Great edit! I suggest removing your "Edit 2" and posting it as an answer (with instructions for how to do it). Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like disabling `Prevent cross-site tracking` makes it work (`Safari > Preferences > Security`)

[image: preferences]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in Safari.  Safari's [Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP)](https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/) *partitions* browser storage (cookies, localStorage, etc) based on the top frame.  Here's the explanation from [WebKit's documentation](https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/#partitioned-third-party-localstorage):

> **Partitioning** is a technology to allow third-parties to use storage and stateful web features, but have those isolated per first-party website. Let’s say adtech.example is a third-party under both news.example and blog.example and that adtech.example uses LocalStorage. With partitioned LocalStorage, adtech.example will get unique storage instances under news.example and blog.example which removes the possibility to do cross-site tracking through LocalStorage.

It's not mentioned in this example, but if the user visited `adtech.example` directly, that's a different domain than `news.example` and `blog.example`, so ITP will give it a new storage instance.

What that means for you is `app.example.com` has different storage instances when it's being loaded directly by the user and inside an iframe on `example.com`.

ITP can be turned off in Safari's Preferences, but it is on by default so assuming this app will be used by external customers, most of the users on Safari will have it turned on.

Safari offers the [Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/) which you may be able to use to solve this.  From [WebKit's blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/):

> The solution is to allow third-party embeds to request access to their first-party cookies when the user interacts with them. To do this, we created the Storage Access API.