# Safari LocalStorage not shared between IFrames hosted on same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, local-storage

We are working on two web applications that are hosted on two different subdomains of the same domain:

- `https://subDomainA.domain.com`
- `https://subDomainB.domain.com`

**Both** web applications are showing an **iFrame** hosted on a third subdomain:

- `https://subDomainC.domain.com`

We are using `postMessage` to communicate between top window and IFrame window.

Within the iFrame shown on **subDomainA**, we are setting an AuthToken:

`localStorage.setItem("AuthToken", "JWTAuthToken")`

When we navigate to **subDomainB** and try to run the following code within the iFrame:

`localStorage.getItem("AuthToken")`

The result is `null`.

- This only happens in the Safari browser.

  - All other browsers **share** the LocalStorage within these IFrames
- We are on the same domain, i.e. the same "eTLD+1" (`domain.com`)
- Doing the exact same thing with cookies **works!**. Just not with LocalStorage
- Opening **subDomainC** directly in the browser and setting the data persists them for the IFrames as well.

Is this a indended behaviour of Safari or do we have an issue with our implementation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the expected behavior in Safari. Safari's Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) partitions browser storage based on the top frame. Here's how WebKit's documentation explains it:

Partitioning is a technology to allow third-parties to use storage and stateful web features, but have those isolated per first-party website. Let’s say adtech.example.com is a third-party under both news.example.com and blog.example.com and that adtech.example.com uses LocalStorage. With partitioned LocalStorage, adtech.example.com will get unique storage instances under news.example.com and blog.example.com which removes the possibility to do cross-site tracking through LocalStorage.

References:

https://webkit.org/tracking-prevention/#partitioned-third-party-localstorage

[Iframe localStorage on Safari and Safari mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401751/iframe-localstorage-on-safari-and-safari-mobile)

In slightly plainer English, https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage says :

Notes on Safari 7+ (OSX, iOS)

All cross-domain local storage access is disabled by default with Safari 7+. This is a result of the "Block cookies and other website data" privacy setting being set to "`From third parties and advertisers`". Any cross-storage client code will not crash, however, it will only have access to a sandboxed, isolated local storage instance. As such, none of the data previously set by other origins will be accessible. If an option, one could fall back to using root cookies for those user agents, or requesting the data from a server-side store.

This may be of use:
https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/

---

In summary, potential solutions include:

1. Use root-domain cookies instead.
2. Use a server-side store, and request the data you need via JSON.
3. If all of your domains are located on the same server, but different Docker images or something, you can Reverse-Proxy and/or Alias all of your websites so they appear as one single domain.
4. Host your iframe you want to share on `example.com` (Not **www**!), and then share it between `one.example.com` and `two.example.com`.
5. Use the [Storage Access API](https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer; just to clarify: Subdomains of the same domain are considered as third-party?

Comment: In the first source it says: "Note that different parties have to be different websites. sub.news.example is considered first-party when loaded under news.example because they are considered to be the same site."

Comment: @ggradnig Correct. The sentence before your quote is this: `If news.example is shown in the URL bar and it loads a subresource from adtech.example, then news.example is first-party and adtech.example is third-party.`

Comment: yeah just with our use case we're on `sub1.news.example` and `sub2.news.example` - so this should be considered "first-party" if we look at the definition of "website" and "first- and third-" party of the terminology section of the documentation :(

Comment: @ggradnig I haven't tested it, but as I understand it, in order to be considered first-party, you'd have to be using `iframe: news.example.com` `domain 1: sub1.news.example.com` `domain 2: sub2.news.example.com` If instead your iframe was sub3.news.example.com, then it'd definitely be considered 3rd-party.

Comment: it seems like it... although the definition of "website" states that a website includes the domain and **all** subdomains - so we should have the same website - and therefore only first-party... could this be a bug in safari?

Comment: we actually switched to a Cookie solution :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the recent updates to the Safari browser (Prevent cross-site tracking) blocks any cookies from being generated when the Matomo domain doesn't match the website it's being loaded from.

This breaks the use of iFrames for Matomo that require cookies to be set (For example the logme feature)

There doesn't seem to be any way to fix this with headers (Eg using CSP or CORS configurations).

**current workarounds exist that I've found:**

1. Disable the "Prevent cross-site tracking" setting in the Privacy settings
2. Redirect the visitor to the page outside of an iFrame to set the cookie - after this the iFrame can load as long as the CORS configuration is correct and the browser isn't completely blocking the iFrame from loading.

I'm not sure how many users are using iFrames that would require cookies to be set, but they would be impacted if any of their users use Safari.