# Safari blocks iframe on the same top level domain

Tags: iframe, safari, postmessage

I have a website running on, lets say **web.test.company.cloud**, which has en iframe from another sub domain on the same top level domain: **tasks.test.company.cloud**. The iframe uses [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to tell the parent document about its height in pixles.

When I open this page in Safari there's a console error saying:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://tasks.test.company.cloud" from accessing a frame with origin "https://web.test.company.cloud". Protocols, domains, and ports must match

It seems that Safari is the only major browser that does this. I find this strange since both documents do share both protocol, domain, and port. While reading about this issue I haven't found any workarounds, so any help on this is appreciated.

Also, will I have the same error in production where parent is running on **company.cloud** while the iframe is on **tasks.company.cloud**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is late, but you may find this post informative:

[Safari LocalStorage not shared between IFrames hosted on same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922558/safari-localstorage-not-shared-between-iframes-hosted-on-same-domain)

In particular, the top answer on ITP might help explain what's happening:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018207

It includes a link to this article about the storage access API:

https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/

The section on sandboxed iframes is intriguing, i.e.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

While going into Safari->Preferences->Privacy and unchecking "Website Tracking: prevent cross-site tracking" isn't much of a solution, I found it temporarily helpful during troubleshooting when trying to narrow down the issue.  Best of luck!